# laravel uploads images but doesn't show theme

Tags: php, laravel, iis, permissions, upload

I designed a web app by Laravel and deployed it on IIS windows server 2022.
this app uploads images correctly but it can't show them.
when I open the security tab on properties of uploaded images I see IISUSER doesn't exist in the permissions list. I change the permission list and add IISUSER to it and everything is ok. what should I do to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
Php first uploads files to `c:/windows/Temp` then move them to `laravel/public/uploadedFiles`. I modified the permissions of the `Temp` folder and add `IISUSER` to the list. after that, I set full control permission to the `IISUSER`.

Answer (score 0):

laravel stores images in public folder only and not store in nested folders, so instead of storing image in public `images\folder1\folder2\image.png` you can directly store public `folder/image.png` in this way

try to move file something like this

```
path= $actuFile->move(public_path('folder'), $name);
```

and retrieve something like this

```
(asset("folder/{$imagName}")
```

This is worked for me.
if its work for you also then welcome in advance.